# Delegating constructor gives segmentation fault when using class field for argument

Tags: c++, native, raspberry-pi3, delegating-constructor

Actually the segmentation fault happens in another program I tried to compile which happens because of this behaviour.

My question is:

> This is a bug or my fault?

Reproducible in any way (even if the `something` field is private or protected) and here is my example:

**main.cc:**

```
#include <iostream>
class Test {
    public:
        const char* something = "SOMETHING HERE!!!";
        Test(const int& number) : Test(something, number) { }
        // XXX: changed `something` to `_something` to make it different
        Test(const char* _something, const int& number) {
            std::cout << _something << std::endl;
            std::cout << number << std::endl; }
        ~Test() { }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Test te1(345);
    Test te2("asdasdad", 34523);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is what happens when compiling with:

```
g++ main.cc -Os -o main
```

and running with:

```
./main
```

the output is:

```
pi@pi:~/ $ ./main
A"�~ <-- this is random
345
asdasdad
34523
```

But when I enable optimization with `-O0` or `-O1` or `-O2` ... the output is only a new line:

```
pi@pi:~/ $ ./main
pi@pi:~/ $
```

G++ version:

```
pi@pi:~/ $ g++ --version
g++ (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1) 6.3.0 20170516
```

Comment: In the next line `const char* something = "SOMETHING HERE!!!";` did you mean `_something`? If not, then this variable wasn't set.

Comment: Everything is as I explained in the question body.

Comment: Quite interesting.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
const char* something = "SOMETHING HERE!!!";
```

The default-initializer on the right is, as its name implies, only used when you don't provide an explicit initializer in a constructor's initializer list. Let's look at yours:

```
Test(const int& number) : Test(something, number) { }
```

Okay, we're delegating to another constructor. That other constructor will perform full initialization, so the default initializer is not used. But... we're passing in the uninitialized value of `something` as parameter.

```
Test(const char* _something, const int& number) { /* ... */ }
```

Uh-oh. Now we're trying to use the value of `_something`, which is a copy of `something`, which is indeterminate. Undefined Behaviour and fire ensue.

You really shouldn't pass the value of a class member as parameter to its constructor, unless you have an infinite supply of fireproof chickens and eggs.

---

The behaviour you're looking for can be obtained by putting the default value in the call to the delegate constructor:

```
Test(const int& number) : Test("SOMETHING HERE!!!", number) { }
```

... or keeping it in a dedicated static variable:

```
static constexpr char *const defaultSomething = "SOMETHING HERE!!!";
Test(const int& number) : Test(defaultSomething, number) { }
```

Comment: Alternatively, a private default constructor would let you write, `Test(const char* _something, const int& number) : Test() { /* ... */ }`

Comment: "You really shouldn't pass the value of a class member as parameter to its constructor, unless you have an infinite supply of fireproof chickens and eggs." -- well done

Answer (score 14):

> This is a bug or my fault?

Oh, it's your fault. The default member initializer is only used to initialize the member object in a non-delegating constructor. According to [[class.base.init]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.base.init#9), emphasis mine:

> **In a non-delegating constructor**, if a given potentially constructed subobject is not designated by a mem-initializer-id
>   (including the case where there is no mem-initializer-list because the
>   constructor has no ctor-initializer), then
>
> - if the entity is a non-static data member that has a default member initializer and either [...] the entity is initialized from its
>     default member initializer as specified in [dcl.init];

So `something` isn't initialized when you pass it to the target constructor. Your program has undefined behavior, and goes bust.

Comment: @Quentin - Well, the OP did ask :P

Comment: Thank you! I accepted the @Quentin's answer because is more complete.

Comment: @MemosElectron - No worries. I upvoted it for the same reason :) That and the mention of fireproof chickens... I really should restock.